# where does the About button go on iPad app?

Tags: user-interface, ipad, ui-design

My iPad app uses a splitView.  Where should I stick a button to bring up an about dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all really depends on your UI and where best it would look. I don't think there's any established rules on what should go where and stuff, aside from the Apple UI guidelines (which are pretty loose in terms of this stuff).

However, to give you a suggestion: assuming you're doing the basic Nav/Tableview for master and regular view for detail, you've got several options:

1) Toolbar along bottom of master for multiple buttons
2) rightBarButton of the navigation controller
3) Toolbar along the top of detail for multiple buttons

Experiment and see what you feel is best. Even better, see what your friends think is best. What you may think as intuitive can be confusing to someone new to your app.